# mysql - select the last n records based on a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores car prices with a structure like:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| make            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| avg_price       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| median_price    | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The data for a given year might be inserted at different times.

```
For example model 'Honda', make 'Accord' might have results like:
+------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| year | avg_price | median_price | model  | created_at          |
+------+-----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| 1992 |   2431.29 |      2000.00 | accord | 2012-02-23 17:31:41 |
| 1993 |   2609.13 |      2195.00 | accord | 2012-02-23 17:31:44 |
| 1994 |   2858.81 |      2400.00 | accord | 2012-02-23 17:31:44 |
| 2000 |   4771.99 |      4450.00 | accord | 2012-02-23 17:31:46 |
| 2001 |   5260.16 |      5000.00 | accord | 2012-02-23 17:31:46 |
| 2000 |   4860.19 |      4795.00 | accord | 2012-08-15 06:09:52 |
| 2001 |   5071.49 |      4990.00 | accord | 2012-08-15 06:09:52 |
| 2002 |   5872.80 |      5795.00 | accord | 2012-08-15 06:09:52 |
| 2003 |   7521.44 |      7950.00 | accord | 2012-08-15 06:09:52 |
| 2004 |   8348.19 |      8495.00 | accord | 2012-08-15 06:09:52 |
```

I would like to retrieve all honda accord data that is the latest for that year of car make.

so in the above example, I would like to retrieve data from 2012-08-15 06:09:52 for years 2000,2001,2002,2003,2004
but the older years would be from the date 2012-02-23 17:31:41

```
select year,avg_price,median_price,model,created_at 
from car_prices 
where make='honda' and    model= 'accord' group by year asc
```

The above query gets distinct data for each year but not the last record inserted for each year.

Any ideas how to get distinct data for each year as well as the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both performance and guarnanteed behaviour, you should create a lookup and join on that.

In your case you want to find the most recent `created_at` value for any given `make, model, year` group.  The sub-query in the code below does that.

Then you join that back on your original data again, finding only the records that have those `make, model, year, created_at` values.

This does mean that it you have more than one record with the same `make, model, year, created_at` values, you will get multiple results for that `make, model, year`.

Ensure that you have an index covering `(make, model, year, created_at)` to make the search for the most recent `created_at` quick, as well as the join.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  car_prices
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    make, model, year, MAX(created_at) as created_at
  FROM
    car_prices
  GROUP BY
    make, model, year
)
  AS most_recent
    ON  car_prices.make       = most_recent.make
    AND car_prices.model      = most_recent.model
    AND car_prices.year       = most_recent.year
    AND car_prices.created_at = most_recent.created_at
WHERE
      most_recent.make  = 'honda'
  AND most_recent.model = 'accord'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM car_prices p
JOIN (SELECT year, MAX(created_at) latest
      FROM car_prices
      WHERE make = 'honda' AND model = 'accord'
      GROUP BY year) mp
ON p.year = mp.year AND p.created_at = mp.latest
WHERE p.make = 'honda' AND p.model = 'accord'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from(
select year,avg_price,median_price,model,created_at 
from car_prices 
where make='honda' and    model= 'accord'     
order by created_at desc,year desc) m
group by year asc
```

Comment: no, that does not work. even after I corrected the sql you entered by switching group by and order by

Comment: Amended. Please try. you could try subquery.

Comment: Not even MySQL provides any ***guarantees*** that this will work.  If you group by `year` but select other columns without using aggregates the values returned are non-deterministic.  Due to the ordering of the inner query it may ***often*** give the results intended, it may even ***normally*** give the results intended, but it is never ***guaranteed*** to give the same results.

Comment: What's the preferred way of getting results for something like I want?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new boolean column that would be set to 0 by default. I use: `is_old`.

```
| is_old            | TINYINT(1) | NO  |     | 0    |                |
```

When inserting price for a new make, model, year, i first do:

```
UPDATE car_prices 
   SET `is_old`=1
WHERE 
   `make`='make_to_insert' AND
   `model`='model_to_insert' AND
   `year`='year_to_insert';
```

Then I insert the new row.

To get recent prices is as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM car_prices
WHERE `is_old` = 0;
```

And your sample query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM
  car_prices
WHERE
      make  = 'honda'
  AND model = 'accord'
  AND is_old = 0;
```